# How do I limit access to my Netlify Serverless function

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, serverless, netlify

I've searched the [netlify docs](https://docs.netlify.com/functions/build-with-javascript/) and I can't figure this out.

I have a serverless function located here

```
/.netlify/functions/orderCreate
```

But I can hit this in my browser or with curl and it tries to create an order. If an attacker finds out about this function they could create thousands fake orders in my db.

I know I can do some simple checks like make sure it is a HTTP post, or make sure it has some valid session ID but I would really like some type of auth or better security.

Because all requests *should* come from the a client side react app via an ajax request can I limit it to the same domain or something ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Netlify doesn't provide a way to check and specific requests based on origin, you could do it manually from inside your function's code and send a 403 response if the Origin isn't your client-side domain:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    if (event.headers["Origin"] !== "https://whateverisyourdomainname.netlify.com")
        return callback(null, { status: 403 })

    // else, do whatever your function does
}
```

Recent browsers do prevent a user from setting the `Origin` header himself. However, **nothing prevents anyone to craft a `curl` request and to spoof the `Origin` header to hit your function**. If you wish to really prevent it, you should set-up **a proper authentication process** to your application.

Comment: Could you suggest a  proper authentication process for this situation ?

Comment: There are many ways to implement an auth process. Netlify itself provides a service for it: https://docs.netlify.com/visitor-access/identity/
If you do not want to use this service and already have a user database (I don't know the context of your app), you can also rely on a JWT authentication. It is pretty easy to setup: https://jwt.io/

Comment: well that header (or any other header) can be just added to the cURL call or any other client that is being used. this is no proper protection.

Answer (score -2):

I'm 4 years too late but hopefully this may help someone. I ran into this issue recently and ended up using Google recaptcha (v3, since its invisible option is not disruptive to user flow) to add a layer of protection to my Netlify function endpoint. Basically I wrapped my entire app (React) in a recaptcha provider, and right before calling the Netlify function, I would get the recaptcha token to send along in the request. The function logic would then verify the token with Google and only if the returned score is satisfactory (like > 0.8), then it would proceed.

This way the function should be as protected as Google recaptcha itself, while not requiring any authentication effort from the users (iirc, recaptcha v3 won't ask users to perform any tasks, it would just assign a low score to the token if it suspects the user is a bot).

Comment: recaptcha is not a replacement for a proper authentication and as good as it is, can be tricked. this answer is misleading.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).